# Does "no-auto-down" and "no-scripts" support pattern matching interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-interface, etc

I tried reading the manual from https://man.cx/interfaces(5) and searching for some open-source code.
But I didn't find any specific description of the option of "no-auto-down" and "no-scripts".

The case I found was:

```bsh
# /etc/network/interfaces

no-auto-down eth0
```

But I want to know, for example, the following example is correct or not:

```bsh
# /etc/network/interfaces

no-auto-down eth0 eth1 eth2
# or
no-auto-down /eth*=eth
```

Comment: I like a theoretical approach, but I like pragmatism as well... Have you actually tried if it works?